# how to break the paragraph lines on a live production using django template tag filters?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filter

I have searched for it but couldn't find an example for live server so that's why posting.
I am working on a template in django in which I need to break the paragraph lines according to the formate that I have applied in django admin panel. let say I have written the same way as it is here :

```
a paragraph a paragraph example
a paragraph a paragraph example a paragraph a paragraph example
a paragraph a paragraph example a paragraph a paragraph example
```

so I have applied linebreaks template filter on it and it is working on the development server.
When I push the source code on live production, the whole paragraph appears as a single line instead of being displayed with 
 tags.
Example on live server:

```
a paragraph a paragraph example<br>a paragraph a paragraph example a paragraph a paragraph example<br>a paragraph a paragraph example a paragraph a paragraph example
```

So I would love to get help from you guys.
thanks in advance.
EDIT:
my .HTML code

```
{% for content_change in content_changes %}
                  <h2>{{ content_change.title }}</h2>
                   <p>{{ content_change.content_changes_logged|linebreaks  }}</p> <br>
                        {{point|linebreaks }}
            {% endfor %}
```

EDIT:
my models.py

```
class ContentChanges(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    content_changes_logged = models.TextField(
        blank=True, help_text="Please use line space for bullet points")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def log_to_bullets(self):
        if '\r\n' in self.content_changes_logged:
            break_point = '\r\n'
        else:
            break_point = '\n'
        return self.content_changes_logged.split(break_point)
```

Comment: Can you show actual code?

Comment: okay let me add the code

Comment: @NixonSparrow  I have added the actual code that is being used

Comment: You didn't mention how you use `log_to_bullets` method. Custom tags I guess, but we still can only guess for now. Has the host got different system/db than your computer?

Comment: everything is same including db

Comment: and let me tell you about the log_to_bullets is being used to convert the paragraph lines into bullets but it is not being used in the current template at the moment

Comment: you can use the template filter " yourstring|safe"  .... but that should never be done if the string is an input from the user.

Comment: no. it is not from end user. it is from admin using django admin panel

Comment: when I use safe, then it doesn't work as expected